# JSDOM triggers webpack polyfill issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, deployment

I have a MERN project. As part of my attempt to deploy the frontend side to a server, I am trying to make it work in node environment.

###### The first issue:

when I attempt to run the following command in terminal:

```
node ./build/static/js/index.js
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser
    at file://Users/123/JAN30/123reporter/front/dashboard/build/static/js/index.js:2:249085
    at file://Users/123/JAN30/123reporter/front/dashboard/build/static/js/index.js:2:249226
    at /Users/123/JAN30/123reporter/front/dashboard/build/static/js/index.js:152:80876
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

which quite makes sense, as I'm attempting to run a .js code, which is expected to  run in an environment of the browser, and I'm attempting to force it to run in a node environment.

So, to solve that, I was attempting to use [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) in the following way:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
const dom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>');
(global as any).window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
const root: ReactDOM.Root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  window.document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

which lead me to ...

###### The second issue:

attempting to use JSDOM as written above triggered the following new issue

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/123/JAN30/123reporter/front/dashboard/node_modules/jsdom/lib'
```

Alright. It make sense, as I am emulating a DOM environment in Nodejs environment, but it doesn't have the module found which Nodejs expects to have.

To solve that, I have added to my webpack.config file's module.export the following field:

```
  node: {
    fs: "empty",
  },
```

now I try to rebuild, which leads me to.. surprise surprise..

###### The third issue:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/123/JAN30/123reporter/front/dashboard/node_modules/jsdom/lib'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

I have tried solving that by adding in the webpack.config the following:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    fallback: {
      path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    },
  },
```

yet, nothing's being changed. tried also modifying to

> path: false;

same result.

Any ideas?

### EDIT:

###### adding webpack config

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.tsx",
  },
  mode: "production",
  node: {
    fs: "empty",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              compilerOptions: { noEmit: false },
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    fallback: {
      path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.config().parsed),
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/static/js"),
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's modify publicPath in (webpack.config.js) since it appears to be an empty string.

```
output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/output'),
           filename: 'fileName.[ext]'
       }
```

Comment: I have added the webpack config to my question.

Comment: @dani_l_n have a look into this article: https://medium.com/@raviroshan.talk/webpack-understanding-the-publicpath-mystery-aeb96d9effb1